# Why running a function with a HTTP query works, but .apply() of the same function fails?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a simple Jupyter notebook with a column of IP addresses that I want to use to create a new one with derived data (a user attached to an IP). To do this I wrote a function that takes the IP and returns user(s).

It works when invoked directly, and fails when used with [`.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).

The core code, common to both cases is

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests

import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)


def getUser(ip: str) -> str:
    r = requests.post('https://example.com/ipinfo.php', json={'ips': [ip]}, verify=False)
    if r.status_code != 200:
        print(f"error getting {ip}: status code {r.status_code}, reason {r.text}")
        return ''
    if not r.json():
        print(f"error getting {ip}: r.json() is empty: {r.json()}")
        return ''
    # there can be several users
    return ','.join([x['user'] for x in r.json()])

p = pd.read_csv("results.csv")
```

When directly running `getUser()`, I get the correct result

```py
getUser('10.11.12.13')

... 'John'
```

The same with `.apply()`

```py
p['user'] = p['IP Address'].apply(getUser)
p['user']

... error getting 10.11.12.13: r.json() is empty: None
    error getting 10.11.12.14: r.json() is empty: None
(...)
```

I cannot understand why a direct call of the function works, put the `.apply()` fails. The error shows that the HTTP call is successful, but the response is empty - despite the right IP being passed.

Is there a way to debug this to break down the one-liner `p['IP Address'].apply(getUser)`?

Comment: Hi, what happens if you try `p["user"] = p["IP Address"].map(lambda x: getUser(x))` or `p["user"] = p.apply(getUser, axis=1)`?